# Delete files older than X days

Tags: shell-script, cron

I am responsible for some daily backups that are over 1GB in size. I don't want to rsync them all to the backup server. I'd like to delete any files in a certain folder, older than X days then rsync the rest. Can this be done via a cron or will it be better to try and write a script?

Comment: use newsyslog , that's what it's for

Comment: Cool, I'll look it up

Answer (score 2):

List all files older than 100 days:

```
find -mtime +100
```

Delete all files older than 100 days:

```
find -mtime +100 -delete
```

For more details read `man find`.

Yes, you can use cron to run a script which runs `find`, but an existing backup solution might be better than reinventing the wheel in your case.

Comment: Can this be used in a specific folder as obviously I don't want to delete every file on the system over X days old? Basically I'd like to run a cron job on the 1st of each month and delete files in a specific folder that are over 30 days old

Comment: Please read `man find` to understand the command and how to use it. Never run any commands you do not understand, yet.

Comment: I have read the man page and I'm still a little unsure, hence the question

Answer (score 2):

```
find /path/to/folder -mtime +30 -delete
```

This did the trick